# Adding CSS to default Google Chrome printing

Tags: php, html, css, google-chrome, printing

I'm printing a page of my PHP application with the ( ctrl + P ) (default printing). How can i make sure that the CSS (tables, padding, cellspacing, background picture with opacity) are printed along on the sheet. I'm calling the CSS from another file.

Thanks for your help and time.

Comment: Background images aren't printed by default and must be toggled by the user.

Comment: Please what do you mean by "toggled by user"? Thanks.

Comment: He means there's a checkbox in the print dialog. You can't force background images to be printed via CSS.

Comment: Chrome (and Safari) actually do not have the option to print background images or colors. This is Firefox/IE only. Print output from Webkit browsers is really lacking in comparison.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this to your HTML page. Now you need to adjust your page manually, for fitting it to the print page. (*use the preview function in Chrome*)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="print.css">
```

The interesting part for the browser is `media=print`

---

You can find some more style commands for printing web pages here:

- [CSS How-to: Optimize Pages for Printing Using CSS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd433064%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Printing a Book with CSS: Boom!](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/boom)
- [complete css guide - Printing](http://www.westciv.com/style_master/academy/css_tutorial/advanced/printing.html)
- [CSS Paged Media - @page Rule](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/css/css_paged_media.htm)

Comment: I'm calling the CSS from another file and what you gave looks like an HTML stuff.

Comment: You need to specify what you mean with "calling from another file". At some point it MUST be added as HTML with such a string.

Comment: I mean the CSS is not no the same page with the HTML, although i have an includes that calls the header and that header contains the link tag.

Comment: Sounds like it's framework based. In symfony 1.x for example you can add a stylesheet like this: `echo stylesheet_tag('print', array('media' => 'print'));` I don't know which you use or *anything* about it. ---- "CSS ain't jesus" - You made me laugh! :)

Answer (score 7):

You must add this

```
html{-webkit-print-color-adjust:exact;}
```

To any css file of the project, ideally the print one, as the others won't load when printing. It will force chrome to use every background color and image exactly as coded.

Comment: Perfect tip for Chrome thanks ! I finally can print those zebra-striped jQuery tables on Chrome too.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It makes life so much better

Answer (score 2):

You will need to include a print stylesheet, as [detailed by Dan Lee](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9912323/1183833). However that's only half the answer. The other half is that Chrome (and Safari) have poor printing options, and cannot print `background-images`, or `background-colors`. I had to figure this all out when trying creating a printable version of [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) that used colors to differentiate between different types of calendar entries.

I include these directions for printing:

> 1. Firefox has the best print output, Internet Explorer is second.
> 2. You may want to turn on the Print Background option in your browser: In Firefox or Internet Explorer: Go to File -> Page Setup -> Check Print Background (colors and images)
> 3. Although Chrome and Safari will work, they do not have the print background options. It will be difficult to differentiate between the types of entries on the calendar.

If your page is simple enough, you can sub in actual `<img>`s instead, and use CSS to stretch and position them behind any text that might be in the `div` or `td`. That wasn't possible for the FullCalendar project I did, but it works fine on a simpler table. It's compatible with Chrome, Firefox, and IE, and doesn't require users to toggle a specific option to get the correct output.

This is as of Chrome 17.0.963.83 and Safari 5.1.4 on Windows.